# Random Forest in R with only character variables

Tags: r, dataset, data, random-forest, dummy-variables

I am new to using random forest in R an my goal is to identify the independent variables which have the highest impact on the dependent variables. I am looking at sales data, and sales is my dependent variable (1 vs. 0) I have other variables which have different levels such as professional status (retired, employed, unemployed), searching for (myself, parent, other) and region (north, west, south), etc...

`summary(data)` provides me with the information that the class of my variables is character (dependent variable shows min, 1st Qu, Media - so I assume R reads it as continuous?) and I believe that a character variable needs to be factored before I can run the randomForest command. Is there a single command that transforms all character into factors?

My second questions is whether I should remove the id of the customer from my imported table, or whether it will affect the results if I keep it in the RF model?

Comment: Predictors that are uncorrelated to the dependant variable may lead to an overfit and should therefore be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the class of the `class(df$dependent)`. You are expecting it to be numeric.

To convert multiple columns to factors, you can do something like this

```
factor_cols <- c("col_1","col_7"), 
df[factor_cols] <- lapply(df[factor_cols], as.factor)
```

If you keep the customer id,  then you will have a problem when applying your model to a new customer.